# Can anyone tell me why my println statement is doing this

Tags: for-loop, modulus, println

I am trying to get my Mod result to print but its doing something strange? Does anyone know why it is printing in a count down fashion?

This is my Driver Class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class gcdTest {

    public static void main(String args[]){


    Random number = new Random();
    int x = number.nextInt(10);
    int y = number.nextInt(10);

     System.out.println("This is it x "+x+ "and y "+ y);
     gcdR.gcdRecursive(x, y);
     //gcdI.gcdIterative(x, y);
}
}
```

This is my method class

```
public class gcdR {
    static int gcdRecursive(int x, int y){
         if (y == 0){

             return x;
         }else{
             int z = (x % y);
             System.out.println("The mod"+z);
             return gcdRecursive(y, (z));
         }          
    }
```

Note:
I am getting a print statement like this

```
This is it x 7 and y 8
The mod 7
The mod 1
The mod 0
```

Why is my code not just printing out

```
This is it x 7 and y 8
The mod 7
```

Answer (score 0):

When you recursively call `gcdRecursive`, your arguments are in the order `y` then `z`, which means that in your example the calculation will be as follows:

1. gcdRecurse(7,8) -> mod = z = 7 % 8 = 7
2. gcdRecurse(8,7) -> mod = z = 8 % 7 = 1
3. gcdRecurse(7,1) -> mod = z = 7 % 1 = 0

Hence, the mod will be calculated each time until `y` is 0, in which case recursion stops.